# Triangular Bullet in Android TextView for Pre-Lollipop devices

Tags: android-layout, textview, android-resources, android-textattributes, android

I Tried character encoding "& #8227;"---> and java strings "\u2023" and also tried pasting directly the Triangular Bullet "‣".

I tried both 
1) Directly specifying in android:text attribute and 
2) Extracting from resource.

All the methods specified above working fine with the Lollipop but none of them working in 4.2.2  and previous android versions.

Instead of the Bullet it is showing some rectangular box.

any ideas how to solve it ??

Comment: Use `\u25b6` (or `\u25b7` for the **empty** flavour), instead. Tested on a 2.2 (Froyo) emulator. This is a very useful resource: http://unicode-table.com/en/

Comment: @DerGolem You again remember me ?? :p.  Thanyou verymuch again post it in answer i will accept and upvote

Comment: @DerGolem tested working like charm

Comment: You see... I always test on older emulators for a reason ;)

Comment: @DerGolem hai do you know how to solve this issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833141/recycler-view-blur-and-repeat-issue. Continue discussion in that link. Thankyou

Comment: No: I never used RecyclerViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying ▶, use `\u25b6` (for displaying ▷, use `\u25b7`).
Tested on a 2.2 (Froyo) emulator: **works**.

This is a very useful resource: http://unicode-table.com/en/