# How to use Get Ordered list in android TextView

Tags: android, textview

how can i get ordered list like view using android text-view.

I need to add an Ordered-List in to my activity i am using a text-view but i can't paste the html directly.so how can i get that ?

```
<TextView
android:Layout_Width="match_parent"
android:Layout_Width="wrap_parent"
android:text="here i want list"/>
```

I also tried to use string resource same result but i can get new lines /n and any similar thing to make a new list Ordered/UN-Ordered ...etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1:-**
You can use a WebView instead of the TextVIew for HTML thing like List and Table.

1)Copy all html to some file abc.html and copy this file to assets folder in your app if not there create one folder and copy it

2) make webview in layout file

3) Access it in java using findview by id and next webview.loadurl("file:///android_asset/your_file_path_in_assets_folder_along_with_file_extension")

i) If your file path in assests folder is Assets/abc/def/xyz.html => file:///android_asset/abc/def/xyz.html

ii) If your file is directly in root folder i.e Assets folder xyz.html => file:///android_asset/xyz.html

**Method 2 :-**
use can use text view to prase html content :- thanks to Rohit5k2 textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your html text here"));

**Method3:-**
Else u can get bullets by using hardcoded text for bullets (for ▶ use \u25b6) take a look at here :- [Triangular Bullet in Android TextView for Pre-Lollipop devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823463/triangular-bullet-in-android-textview-for-pre-lollipop-devices)

I think these are enough to guide you :p

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i forget to mention the second option, thanks to you

Comment: Your answer is good but after many searches i got an error in line 
File:///asset/abc.html  it should be like this 
File:///android_asset/abc.html

Comment: @KhizarHayat yep, sorry for that. Changed it, thanks for the info.

Comment: But he asked for ordered list. Even if you add "ol" tag of html and later use Html.fromHtml() , it still gives you an un ordered list with black dots , instead of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text_view"
android:Layout_Width="match_parent"
android:Layout_Width="wrap_parent"
android:text="here i want list"/>
```

In Code

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your html text here"));
```

Comment: Sorry i am newbee please upvote my question. so i can upvote both you guys

Comment: @AshTheJuggernaut i think you can publicly ask like that anyway i already upvoted :P

Comment: @AshTheJuggernaut: There you go +1