# Ordered list from html in android TextView

Tags: android, html, textview

My intention is **to load HTML data into a textView as an ordered (1,2,3,4,.....n) list**.But **the UI shows always in bullet points rather than an ordered list**. I have searched and tried to follow some solutions but nothing works. Your help would be amazing and much appreciated.

*The procedure I followed is given underneath.*

```
dataBinding.tvBody.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
      text,
      HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_DIV,
)
```

*Here the value of **text** is,*

```
<div><b>Test Data Added Here For EN</b></div><ol><li>15% on discount on video consultation and tele consultation with family medicine doctor, nutritionist, gynecologist, physiotherapist, &amp; dental surgeon.</li><li>15% discount on home sample collections on any pathological test &amp; imaging test.</li><li>15% discount on the 1st visit with family medicine doctor’s fee.</li><li>5% discount on annual health checkups.</li></ol>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Get Ordered list in android TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826127/how-to-use-get-ordered-list-in-android-textview)

Comment: Yes, I have looked at it. The first method seems not feasible for me because just to show some text I don't wanna use webView and the second method isn't working.

Comment: `text,` ? Please assign your text variable in your code so we see what you do.

Comment: I have assigned the value of text. Can you please check?