# Recycler View Blur and Repeat Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

My app contains an activity containing a toolbar(app-bar), ad-mob and an fragment.thr frament consists a RecyclerView.

I just used basic RecylerView methods in its adapter for inflation and onbindview.....etc, and i used Linear-Layout Inflater.

It works fine most of the times but some times (say 1 out of 50 times) it blurs and repeats views in the Top and Bottom of the screen including ToolBar(App-Bar) and navigation-bar and also some part of recyler view and there are no errors in the LogCat.

The blur areas are not constant sometimes it blurs most of the screen sometimes only someparts of screen are blurred

**Here is the Screen Shots:- for Reference i also included the adapter Positions**

**ScreenShot :- Error 1**
[image: ScreenShot :- Error 1]

**ScreenShot :- Error 2**
[image: ScreenShot :- Error 2]

**What i tried to remove blur and is that solved the Probelm ??**

**Update-1** i tried using **setHasSizeFixed(true)** because the adapter data wont change the size of my views all are 90dp height. **Not Solved the Problem**.